# Can we compare two or more custom dimensions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is there a possible way to build following case metrics using Google Analytics ?

```html
ID      Name    Action
1        A       Test
2        B       Test1
3        C       Test2
4        D       Test
5        E       Test3
6        F       Test1
```

Here, Id, Name and Actions are three different custom dimensions data collected form a page. Can we filter them using the action custom dimension? Like, If we choose to filter "Test" Action, it should display its corresponding Name and ID as well like below:

```html
ID      Name    Action
1        A       Test
4        D       Test
```

PS: I have placed the table in code snippet to avoid de-formation after submission.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom report with type flat
enter your dimension and metrics
add a filter that matches your condition and see the report.

Hope this helps,
Cheers Analytics ML

Comment: Yes, I think it works. But, Google analytics isn't allowing to create a custom report without custom Metrics. Any idea to get rid of Custom metrics in custom reports?

Comment: Unfortunately google analytics does not allow that, a custom report must be created with a dimension & metrics pair
just use users metrics that will probably do the trick